# Epic Online Services errors.com.epicgames.common.policy_missing_action

Tags: unreal-engine5

been experimenting with UE5 and EOS

I havent filled in the branding section completely in the dev portal for EOS (in draft) as I dont have a policy or game logo

I have the game logging in fine (using accountportal) and that returns success and I get the overlay, so no issues, but when I try and create a session it fails with the below Error

[2022.05.07-10.50.43:574][724]LogEOSSDK: Warning: LogEOS: Error response received from backend. ServiceName=[Sessions], OperationName=[CreateSession], Url=[], HttpStatus=[403], ErrorCode=[errors.com.epicgames.common.policy_missing_action], NumericErrorCode=[UNSET], ErrorMessage=[Client  missing matchmaking:createSession], CorrId=[EOS-Cq8EcZDt1UCJ_3H0vBAlMw-P4g0uuJPKUeOfcjLzhEBIQ-p7QMqQjV-EyAynCi_1iBjw]

If I set the "isLan" option it works fine no issues, have I missed something in the setup to stop it working online or is it because the branding is in draft and not verified that it only allows Lan?

Answer (score 0):

This was potentially due to the online portal client policy, was pretty sure I had it so the client to create/host sessions but i went through it all again and now it seems to work